# Always Getting an HTML in Response from RTC

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, rational-team-concert, ibm-jazz, oslc

It seems like the RTC server doesn't like my url request. I can essentially add whatever I want after the "host" part of the url and get the same result. So I'm guessing something about what I've got is wrong. Following the answer from my previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61108722/rtc-simple-id-query-results-in-404/61109914), I'm pretty sure I have the right url from the "services" file in the `<oslc_cm:simpleQuery><dc:title>Change request queries</dc:title>` tag. So I'm not sure if there's something else it doesn't like? It no longer fails authentication and I'm now using form-based rather than basic, so I don't think it's authentication-related. It just seems to ignore anything and everything but still knows my credentials aren't wrong. Any ideas?

Update: I've also tried swapping all the colons with %3A as the Jazz [documentation](https://jazz.net/wiki/bin/view/Main/WorkItemAPIsForOSLCCM20#Examples) didn't seem particularly consistent in their examples if that was necessary or not. Same results though.

```cs
        string host = "https://my.host.com:9443/ccm/";
        string item = host + "oslc/contexts/_MySp3ci4lK3Y/workitems?" +
                                  "oslc.where=dcterms:identifier=%222494443%22&" +
                                  "oslc.properties=dcterms:title,dcterms:identifier&" +
                                  "oslc.prefix=dcterms=%3Chttp://purl.org/dc/terms/%3E";
        Debug.Log("Request");
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(item);
        request.Accept = "application/json";
        request.Headers.Add("OSLC-Core-Version", "2.0");
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        string AuthHeader = response.Headers["X-com-ibm-team-repository-web-auth-msg"];
        //check if authentication has failed
        if ((AuthHeader != null) && AuthHeader.Equals("authrequired"))
        {
            Debug.Log("Authentication Required");
            HttpWebRequest _formPost = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(host + "authenticated/j_security_check"); // Same response without the "authenticated/j_security_check"
            _formPost.Method = "POST";
            _formPost.Timeout = 30000;
            _formPost.Headers.Add("OSLC-Core-Version", "2.0");
            _formPost.CookieContainer = request.CookieContainer;
            _formPost.Accept = "text/xml";
            _formPost.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

            Byte[] _outBuffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(credentials); //store in byte buffer
            _formPost.ContentLength = _outBuffer.Length;
            Stream _str = _formPost.GetRequestStream();
            _str.Write(_outBuffer, 0, _outBuffer.Length); //update form
            _str.Close();

            //FormBasedAuth Step2:submit the login form and get the response from the server
            HttpWebResponse _formResponse = (HttpWebResponse)_formPost.GetResponse();

            string _rtcAuthHeader = _formResponse.Headers["X-com-ibm-team-repository-web-auth-msg"];
            //check if authentication has failed
            if ((_rtcAuthHeader != null) && _rtcAuthHeader.Equals("authfailed"))
            {
                Debug.Log("Authentication Failed");
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                //login successful
              // *** Still says AuthRequired here for some reason ***
                Debug.Log("Auth Header = " + _rtcAuthHeader); 
                _formResponse.GetResponseStream().Flush();
                _formResponse.Close();
                //FormBasedAuth Step3: Resend the request for the protected resource.
                response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            }
        }
        else if (AuthHeader == null)
        {
            Debug.Log("AuthHeader Null");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("AuthHeader = " + AuthHeader);
        }

        Debug.Log("Response Stream");
        Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
        int read;
        while ((read = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            // Prints out an HTML Doc rather than a JSON string.
            Debug.Log(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer));
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I've come to understand.

The comment "// *** Still says AuthRequired here for some reason ***" is telling of the fact that authorization is indeed not occurring. The header value for "X-com-ibm-team-repository-web-auth-msg" will indeed be null when it is officially no longer required.

It is failing because:

1. The _formPost itself needs basic authentication to post the form values
2. The CookieContainer is null. Creating a new CookieContainer allows for the authentication to proceed.
3. The "authenticated/j_security_check" is not correct. It should simply be "j_security_check".
4. When requesting the data a second time after authenticating, a new request must be created and using the CookieContainer from the original.